# Exporting texts and datatable from shiny to pdf

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to write an app for work to allow some simple advice for patients on certain drugs to be presented in a datatable format, with the option to add some additional text.  I've looked around to see if there is some way of exporting the the text and datatable to a pdf so that we can print it out but have not been successful so far.  This is the code for the app:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(xtable)


insulin <- readRDS("insulin.rda")

# User Interface

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Pre-operative Advice on Insulin - For Patients with Diabetes Undergoing Elective Surgery v0.1"),

  p("Please refer to Guideline on Shared Drive or Intranet for full guidance"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Patient Name and Date of Birth (Optional)"),

      textInput("px_name", label = "Patient Name", placeholder = "Patient Name"),
      textInput("dob", label = "Date of Birth or CHI", placeholder = "Date of Birth or CHI"),

      selectInput("DM", "What type of diabetes does patient have?",
                  c("Type One" = "Type 1",
                    "Type Two on Insulin" = "Type 2"),
                  selected = "Type One"),

      selectInput("time", "Is patient on morning or afternoon list?",
                  c("Morning List" = "AM",
                    "Afternoon List" = "PM"),
                  selected = "Morning"),

      checkboxGroupInput("class", "Which type(s) of insulin is patient on?",
                         c("Long and Intermediate acting",
                           "Pre-Mixed",
                           "Rapid or Short acting"))

      ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("insulin_sel"),

      h3(textOutput(outputId = "px_name")),

      br(),

      h4(textOutput(outputId = "dob")),

      br(),

      tableOutput("table"),




    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$px_name <- renderText({input$px_name})

  output$dob <- renderText({input$dob})


  output$insulin_sel <- renderUI({

    insulin_subset <- insulin %>% filter(DM == input$DM, 
                                         Time == input$time, 
                                         Class %in% input$class)

    selectizeInput("name", "Type in name of insulin",
                   choices = list("Type in insulin name" = "", 
                                  "Names" = insulin_subset$Name), 
                                  selected = NULL, 
                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                  options = NULL)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({

    insulin_subset <- insulin %>% filter(DM == input$DM, 
                                         Time == input$time, 
                                         Class %in% input$class)

    tab <- insulin_subset %>% filter(Name %in% input$name)

    xtable(tab)

  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is part of the instructions:

```
> dput(insulin)
structure(list(DM = c("Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1"), Time = c("AM", "AM", 
"AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
"PM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
"PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
"PM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "AM", "AM", 
"AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
"AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), Class = c("Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Long and Intermediate acting", 
"Long and Intermediate acting", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", 
"Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", 
"Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", 
"Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Pre-Mixed", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", "Rapid or Short acting", 
"Rapid or Short acting"), Name = c("Abasaglar", "Lantus", "Levemir", 
"Toujeo", "Tresiba", "Insulatard", "Humulin I", "Abasaglar", 
"Lantus", "Levemir", "Toujeo", "Tresiba", "Insulatard", "Humulin I", 
"Abasaglar", "Lantus", "Levemir", "Toujeo", "Tresiba", "Insulatard", 
"Humulin I", "Abasaglar", "Lantus", "Levemir", "Toujeo", "Tresiba", 
"Insulatard", "Humulin I", "Humulin M3", "Novomix 30", "Insuman Comb 15/25/50", 
"Humalog Mix 25/50", "Humulin M3", "Novomix 30", "Insuman Comb 15/25/50", 
"Humalog Mix 25/50", "Humulin M3", "Novomix 30", "Insuman Comb 15/25/50", 
"Humalog Mix 25/50", "Humulin M3", "Novomix 30", "Insuman Comb 15/25/50", 
"Humalog Mix 25/50", "Novorapid/Fiasp", "Humalog", "Apidra", 
"Humulin S", "Actrapid", "Novorapid/Fiasp", "Humalog", "Apidra", 
"Humulin S", "Actrapid", "Novorapid/Fiasp", "Humalog", "Apidra", 
"Humulin S", "Actrapid", "Novorapid/Fiasp", "Humalog", "Apidra", 
"Humulin S", "Actrapid"), Plan = c("Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", "Usual dose at usual time", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", "Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", "Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", "Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", "Half usual morning dose taken with a sugary drink at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", 
"Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", "Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Half usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am", 
"Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", 
"Omit breakfast dose", "Omit breakfast dose", "Usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am, oral fluids until 11am, omit lunchtime dose", 
"Usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am, oral fluids until 11am, omit lunchtime dose", 
"Usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am, oral fluids until 11am, omit lunchtime dose", 
"Usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am, oral fluids until 11am, omit lunchtime dose", 
"Usual morning dose taken with a light breakfast at 7am, oral fluids until 11am, omit lunchtime dose"
)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I've tried the method described [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html).  I pasted the code from the link directly but seem to be getting nowhere with the following error:

```
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="report.Rmd": The system cannot find the file specified
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="report.Rmd": The system cannot find the file specified
Warning: Error in abs_path: The file 'report.Rmd' does not exist.
  [No stack trace available]
```

At this point, even if I could just export the DT to a pdf would be useful.

Edit: For the query about displaying an output object.
Code on server side:

```
my_ortho_table <- reactive({
    ortho_table <- drugsUI %>%
      filter(Ortho == "yes") %>%
      select(Name, Recommendations)
    return(ortho_table)
  })  

  observeEvent(input$ortho, {
    if(input$ortho == "yes"){
      output$ortho_tab <- renderTable({
        xtable(my_ortho_table())})
      output$ortho_text <- renderText("Additional information for patients undergoing hip and knee replacement or revision,
                                      if taking the following medications")
    }else{
      output$ortho_tab <- NULL
      output$ortho_text <- NULL
    }
```

On the ui side:

```
textOutput("ortho_text"),
tableOutput("ortho_tab"),
```

It is the `ortho_text` I would like to display (or not, depending on the input) in the pdf.

Further Edit:
This is what I tried

```
my_ortho_table <- reactive({
    ortho_table <- drugsUI %>%
      filter(Ortho == "yes") %>%
      select(Name, Recommendations)


    if(input$ortho == "yes"){
      output$ortho_tab <- renderTable({
        xtable(ortho_table)})

    }else{
      output$ortho_tab <- NULL
      }
  })  

  my_ortho_text <- reactive({
    if(input$ortho == "yes"){

      output$ortho_text <- renderText("Additional information for patients undergoing hip and knee replacement or revision,
                                      if taking the following medications")
    }else{

      output$ortho_text <- NULL
    }

  })
```

with the corresponding output:

```
output$ortho_table <- my_ortho_table()


output$ortho_text <- my_ortho_text()
```

but got the following error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Comment: Did you create a `report.Rmd` file to use in RMarkdown that includes the layout of what you want in the report? If not, you will get this error. This is the example report used in the Shiny example you linked to: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/016-knitr-pdf/report.Rmd If you need additional help with this let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have a `report.Rmd` file already created in R Markdown (or it couldn't find the file).

Below is code that should generate a report. The first part is updated `ui` and `server` code. You can add `format` to allow for different file formats if desired, and a download button. You will want your filtering done in a `reactive` block.

The second part is an example `report.Rmd` file that will show the data table using `xtable`. You can further modify your report to include whatever information you want and other boilerplate info.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(xtable)
library(rmarkdown)

insulin <- readRDS("insulin.rda")

# User Interface

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Pre-operative Advice on Insulin - For Patients with Diabetes Undergoing Elective Surgery v0.1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Patient Name and Date of Birth (Optional)"),
      textInput("px_name", label = "Patient Name", placeholder = "Patient Name"),
      textInput("dob", label = "Date of Birth or CHI", placeholder = "Date of Birth or CHI"),
      selectInput("DM", "What type of diabetes does patient have?",
                  c("Type One" = "Type 1",
                    "Type Two on Insulin" = "Type 2"),
                  selected = "Type One"),
      selectInput("time", "Is patient on morning or afternoon list?",
                  c("Morning List" = "AM",
                    "Afternoon List" = "PM"),
                  selected = "Morning"),
      checkboxGroupInput("class", "Which type(s) of insulin is patient on?",
                         c("Long and Intermediate acting",
                           "Pre-Mixed",
                           "Rapid or Short acting")),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("insulin_sel"),
      h3(textOutput(outputId = "px_name")),
      br(),
      h4(textOutput(outputId = "dob")),
      br(),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  my_insulin_table <- reactive({
    insulin_subset <- insulin %>% filter(DM == input$DM, 
                                         Time == input$time, 
                                         Class %in% input$class)
    tab <- insulin_subset %>% filter(Name %in% input$name)
  })

  output$px_name <- renderText({input$px_name})
  output$dob <- renderText({input$dob})
  output$insulin_sel <- renderUI({
    insulin_subset <- insulin %>% filter(DM == input$DM, 
                                         Time == input$time, 
                                         Class %in% input$class)
    selectizeInput("name", "Type in name of insulin",
                   choices = list("Type in insulin name" = "", 
                                  "Names" = insulin_subset$Name), 
                   selected = NULL, 
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = NULL)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    xtable(my_insulin_table())
  })

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `report.Rmd` file could include the following as an example:

````
# Pre-operative Advice on Insulin

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
xtable(my_insulin_table())
```
````

Note the use of `asis` for `xtable` to remove the additional comments added when a table is created. Also, for this example with `xtable` it targets pdf format only.

**Edit**: To pass the name and date of birth to your report, you can also use parameters.

First, add the parameters in a list in your `render` statement:

```
out <- render('report.Rmd', 
        params = list(name = input$px_name, dob = input$dob),
        switch(input$format,
          PDF = pdf_document(), 
          HTML = html_document(), 
          Word = word_document()
      ))
```

Then reference them as inline r code in your `report.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Pre-operative Advice on Insulin"
output: pdf_document
params:
  name: 'NULL'
  dob: 'NULL'
---

# Demographics

Name: `r params[["name"]]`

Date of Birth: `r params[["dob"]]`

# Insulin Schedule

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
xtable(my_insulin_table())
```
````

Comment: That is wonderful and such a simple mistake to have made!  I am still very new to this, so thanks for your help. For my own education, how does making the `filter` in a `reactive` block make a difference?

Comment: The `reactive` block will update whenever the `input` changes. I like having my data filters in one place - that both the `output$table` and the `report.Rmd` can reference and get identical results (without repeating code). You could pass data as parameters to your .Rmd file as an alternative, but then you're repeating your filters in the report.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question, how do I go about including the text output `output$px_name` and `output$dob` into the Rmd file?

Comment: Those could be passed as parameters. I'll edit the answer in a moment to demonstrate...see edited answer above.

Comment: Thank you, I am learning so much. Considering I have never done any coding until about 6 months ago, you have no idea what your help means to me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Great progress over 6 months! Please let me know if any other questions come up. Good luck!

Comment: Another related question, what can I do if the text I want to export to the pdf is an `output` object?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more on what you need? What is the object (a table, plot, text, or something else)? Is it something different from what was in your example?

Comment: I have an `observeEvent` on the `server` side which depending on the input, will give `output$ortho_text <- renderText("some text")` or `output$ortho_text <- NULL`, the `ui` side would be `renderText("ortho_text")`.  It is the `ortho_text` which I wish to display in the pdf.

Comment: @LarryLi - there are a number of different ways to go about this, depending on a number of factors. Maybe to make this simple, make another `reactive` block specifically for the `ortho_text` (e.g., `my_ortho_text`). In that block, have an `if` statement for `input$ortho == "yes"` which will return either a string of text (yes) or something else. Then, your `output$ortho_text` will just call that block (`my_ortho_text()`). In your .Rmd, call the same block. If you do that, you won't need a separate `observeEvent`. You will need a similar `if` statement in `my_ortho_table` though.

Comment: would you mind reviewing the addition edit? I tried what you suggested but seems to have encountered a new error.  I appreciate your help, let me know if you're fed up and I will ask a new question to the forum!

Comment: You don't want to have `output` within a `reactive` block. It should be like your `my_ortho_table` that just returned a data frame, but instead, you'll want it to return a string. Then your `output$ortho_text` would call the block (e.g., `my_ortho_text()`).

Comment: So `my_ortho_text <- reactive({})` would contain code to check your `input$ortho` and return either some string or NULL (whatever you like). Your `output$ortho_text` doesn't need any `if` statement - it should be simple, just calling `my_ortho_text()`. We could start a chat to discuss further, or you can post a new question. I'm sorry if I made more confusing. Again, there's multiple ways to go about this, but thought this might be easiest and more consistent with what you have so far.

Comment: To clarify, for your output you need: `output$ortho_text <- renderText({my_ortho_text()})` - I think you forgot `renderText`?

Comment: I will try this, would the Rmd then simply be ```my_ortho_text()``` within the code chunk or how do I render the text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202729/discussion-between-larry-li-and-ben).

Comment: I’ll be available in abt 20 minutes